# Cargar DataTable dinámicamente con JSON (convertido de Excel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datatables

Estimados tengo unos registros de Excel convertidos a formato JSON, estos quiero que se carguen en un DataTable. Tengo el código que convirtió Excel a JSON en el Archivo index.js pero ahora no se como abordar la carga a un DataTable.

index.js

```
var XLSX = require("xlsx");

const ExcelAJSON = () => {
  const excel = XLSX.readFile(
    "C:\\Users\\jazo2\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\convertir un Excel a JSON con Node JS\\Datos.xlsx"
  );
  var nombreHoja = excel.SheetNames; // regresa un array
  let datos = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(excel.Sheets[nombreHoja[0]]);

  const jDatos = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    const dato = datos[i];
    jDatos.push({
      ...dato,
      Fecha: new Date((dato.Fecha - (25567 + 2)) * 86400 * 1000)
    });
  }
  console.log(jDatos);
};
ExcelAJSON();
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, este es un buen caso para que te apoyes en algún asistente AI como co-pilot o chatGPT, intenta avanzar con el asistente y si hay dudas particulares (que siempre surgen) modificas la pregunta con mas detalles para que podamos ayudarte.